# In Scala 2, what are possible ways to write a shortcut of a partial function without triggering unchecked warning?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-compiler, partialfunction, scala-2

This is a follow-up question of:

[In Scala 3: Why runtime pattern matching can't work reliably on duck type using JVM reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75440665/in-scala-3-why-runtime-pattern-matching-cant-work-reliably-on-duck-type-using)

I'm trying to create a pattern matching implementation in Scala that is more resilient to type erasure. It should still rely on only JVM reflection on class but can degrade smoothly to alternatives in case of a runtime sanity check or class cast error.

The signature of my implementation looks like this:

```
@unchecked
case class Match[T](self: T) {

  def apply[R](
      @unchecked cases: PartialFunction[T, R]*
  ): R = ???
}
```

When testing it on a case that involves type erasure:

```
    trait H {

      type Unknown <: String

      Match("abc": Serializable).apply(
        { case v: Unknown => 1 },
        { case v: Any => 2 }
      )
    }
```

I still got the warnings:

```
[Warn] /xxx.scala:20:19: abstract type pattern Has.this.Unknown is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[Warn] /xxx.scala:20:16: The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
```

It appears that @unchecked annotation has no effect on suppressing compiler message. This effectively rules out possibility to use partial function in my definition.

How can this warning be suppressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just put `@unchecked` in wrong places. It's for annotating types (making a type [AnnotatedType](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types$AnnotatedType.html) internally). Try to annotate the type in type pattern. Usage example is in the scaladoc of `@unchecked` and in Scala spec.

```
case class Match[T](self: T) {
  def apply[R](
                cases: PartialFunction[T, R]*
              ): R = ???
}

trait H {
  type Unknown <: String

  Match("abc": Serializable).apply(
    { case v: Unknown @unchecked => 1 },
    { case v: Any => 2 }
  )
}
```

Scaladoc: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/unchecked.html

Scala spec: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/11-annotations.html#scala-compiler-annotations

[What is correct syntax for @unchecked in a fold operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785723/what-is-correct-syntax-for-unchecked-in-a-fold-operation)

[Scala: recursively pattern match a heterogeneous list, obtaining the correct type of each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144912/scala-recursively-pattern-match-a-heterogeneous-list-obtaining-the-correct-typ)

[Scala: pattern matching on a path-dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998833/scala-pattern-matching-on-a-path-dependent-type)

Comment: hmmm, strange, I remembered trying that before